# Add validator in handsontable and allow to insert columns

Tags: validation, insert, handsontable

I need add validation for columns in handsontable, but possibility for add new column is necessary for me. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic columns for Handsontable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185751/how-to-create-dynamic-columns-for-handsontable)

Comment: No, I need give this possibility for users. I show them current table, and they can edit it and add new columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

minSpareRows: 1 is the answer for adding a new row:

```
var tbl = new Handsontable(container, {
    ...
    minSpareRows: 1,
    ...
});
```

and for validation:

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-data-validation.html

Comment: Yes, but we need add not only rows and columns as well. And minSpareCols and columns as properties are not compatible...